# Windows XP find most recently updated files

Tags: windows-xp

How to **find the latest created / accessed / modified files** in the Windows XP OS ?

I need it because some setup.exe copies some files and then it disappears without any trace, so I'd like to know what files and where are created

Answer (score 4):

Do a Windows search and specify a time window in the 'modified' section.

Comment: Yep but it does allow to set the Day only. I need a Time Interval

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me so just enter the date of the day the files were modified (today I guess), then order by the date modified column, which includes the time.